# Join doesnt distinct my columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using this code for making join two tables:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    i.id,
    b.barcode
FROM
    inventory i
    JOIN barcodes b ON b.id = i.id
ORDER BY
    i.id
```

The problem is that i have many Barcodes witch are Connecting with the same id.

This is my Output

```
id      barcode

1       10001
1       10002
1       1003
2       10009
2       10101
```

I want my result having only one id, and giving me first Barcode of my table for this id.My desiring result is:

```
id      barcode

1       10001
2       10009
```

Comment: `and giving me first Barcode`, how can we know which one is the first?

Comment: Just one of them.I dont care which will be the first cause in my code i will use only id.

Comment: If you'll only use ID then why don't you just `select distinct id` instead of `id, barcode`?

Comment: If you use `INNER JOIN` only as a filter, there is no need to include extra fields in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` (also, you should actually try to figure out which barcode you actually want):

```
SELECT  i.id,
        b.barcode
FROM inventory i
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM barcodes
             WHERE id = i.id
             ORDER BY barcode) b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rows in a table are not ordered, so there is no first, second or last record. You'd have to specify which record or barcode you want. Here is an example for the smallest barcode number per ID:

```
select id, min(barcode)
from barcodes
group by id;
```

Comment: Filter criteria belongs in the where clause by the way. So if you want to limit the results to IDs present in inventory then add `where id in (select id from inventory)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    i.id,
    MIN(b.barcode) AS barcode
FROM
    inventory i
    JOIN barcodes b ON b.id = i.id
GROUP BY 
    i.id
ORDER BY 
    i.id
```

Comment: No need for the `DISTINCT`  keyword here

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `SELECT DISTINCT` - it's equivalent to `GROUP BY *`, which is not what you want.

Instead, you need to reduce `barcodes` down so it has a `1:1` relationship with `inventory`, except right now it's a `1:m` relationship.

As @Lamak mentioned in the comments, you haven't specified *which* barcode should be used for a given `inventory` row. SQL itself is not too concerned with ordering, that's why there's no `FIRST` or `LAST` aggregate functions (though there is `MIN` and `MAX`) - in SQL data has no notion of ordering until you explicitly specify it with `ORDER BY` (or use `OVER` with an aggregate).

For something quick, just use `MIN` or `MAX`:

```
SELECT
    i.id,
    MIN( b.barcode ) AS barcode
FROM
    inventory i
    INNER JOIN barcodes b ON b.id = i.id
GROUP BY
    i.id
ORDER BY
    i.id
```